# Script for Outlook Rule that Saves Attachment based on date

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

The intent is to use a rule to trigger a script that saves the attached files of an email if the created date is equal to today. Next, the script would delete all items from the folder that do not have the same created date.

I can run the code, but it doesn't do anything.

```vb
Public Sub SaveAttachments(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim sSaveFolder As String
    Dim today As Date 'today's date
    Dim adate As Date 'date of attachment
    
    today = Date
    
    sSaveFolder = "filepath"
        
    For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
        adate = oAttachment.DateCreated
        If DateDiff("d", today, adate) = 0 Then
        oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
        End If
    Next oAttachment
    
    Dim objFSO, objFolder, objfile As Object
    
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(sSaveFolder)
    
    For Each objfile In objFolder.files
        If Format(objfile.DateCreated, "DD-MM-YYYY") <> Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY") Then
            Kill objfile
        End If
    Next objfile
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging this?  Do the statements inside your `If` blocks actually execute?

Comment: @TimWilliams, I actually got it figured out. The key issue was that the .DateCreated method applies to files, not attachment objects. I used the .Senton method instead, and everything is now working as expected. Took me way too long to figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
Public Sub SaveAttachmentsToDisk(MItem As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim oAttachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim sSaveFolder As String
Dim keepfile As String

sSaveFolder = "filepath"
    
For Each oAttachment In MItem.Attachments
    sdate = MItem.SentOn
    If Format(sdate, "DD-MM-YYYY") = Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY") Then
    oAttachment.SaveAsFile sSaveFolder & oAttachment.DisplayName
    keepfile = oAttachment.DisplayName
    End If
Next oAttachment

Dim objFSO, objFolder, objfile As Object

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(sSaveFolder)

For Each objfile In objFolder.files
    If InStr(objfile.Name, keepfile) = 0 Then
        Kill objfile
    End If
Next objfile

End Sub
```

Comment: Absolutely correct!

Comment: I suggest if mail is received between shutdown and midnight the next time Outlook is opened`.SentOn` will be before `Date`. The attachment will not be saved.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I don’t think this should be a problem, as the attachment I’m wanting saved is from a subscription email that gets sent at the same time every morning.

Answer (score 0):

The [Attachment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachment?view=outlook-pia) class from the Outlook object model doesn't provide the `DateCreated` property.

Comment: yep, took me way to long to realize that fact